# ASP.Net MVC - dynamic link to download *.pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Yellow,
I have two strings - FileName and UString. And i wanna download this file by a download button. The path of the file has to be dynamical and the same story about FileName
HomeController :

```
    public FileResult GetPdf() 
    {
        Read read = new Read(); //in Read class i have the data readed from XML (thats the file name and unique string.
        string Ustring = read.VratUstring(); //UString - is the containing folder of .pdf
        string FileName = read.VratFileName(); // Name of file

        return File(@"E:/Miriam/"+ Ustring +"/" + FileName +".pdf", "application/pdf",  FileName +".pdf");

    }
```

And the button :

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input type="submit" value="" class="myButton" formaction="GetPdf" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the result i get from browser is this :

Soubor E:\Miriam.pdf nebyl nalezen. //thast mean file E:Miriam/.pdf wasnt found. But im missing there the ustring and file name.
The path should look like this :
E:\Miriam\dlvhkjclkjvhklcDKKF2\CelejmPDF.pdf

namespace MVC_SAFE.Models
{
    class Read
    {
        public string JobName { get; set; }  //Name of job
        public int Index { get; set; } //verzion
        public string FileName { get; set; }  //Cele jmeno *.pdf a *.xml
        public string Customer { get; set; } //Zakaznik
        public string URL { get; set; }  //URL html stranky (odkaz z mailu)
        public string UString { get; set; }   //unikatni klic pro html sooubor a adresar z eska
        public string Lang { get; set; } //Jazykova verze
        public DateTime Created { get; set; } //cas odeslani

```
    //precte a vypise hodnoty vsech nodu (uzlu)
    public void Precti(string ustring) //unikatni klic zadany zakaznikem
    {
        //nacteni vstupniho xml
        List<Uzivatel> uzivatele = new List<Uzivatel>();  //pripojuju tridu uzivatel
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(@"E:/Miriam/" + ustring + "/" + ustring + ".xml")) //cesta k *.xml souboru + hodnoty z xml jsou ulozene v xr
        {
            string jobName = "";   //Jmeno zakazky
            int index = 0;  //Verze korektury
            string fileName = "";  //Cele jmeno *.pdf a *.xml
            string customer = "";  //Zakaznik
            string url = "";   //URL html stranky (odkaz z mailu)
            string uString = "";  //unikatni klic pro html sooubor a adresar z eska
            string lang = ""; //Jazykova verze
            DateTime created = DateTime.Now; //cas odeslani
            string element = "";  //element tagu


            while (xr.Read())
            {
                if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)  //
                {
                    element = xr.Name; // název aktuálního elementu
                }
                else if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) //nacita hodnoty elementu

                    switch (element)
                    {
                        case "JobName":
                            jobName = xr.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Index":
                            index = int.Parse(xr.Value);
                            break;
                        case "FileName":
                            fileName = xr.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Customer":
                            customer = xr.Value;
                            break;
                        case "URL":
                            url = xr.Value;
                            break;
                        case "UString":
                            uString = xr.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Lang":
                            lang = xr.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Created":
                            created = DateTime.Parse(xr.Value);
                            break;

                    }

                else if ((xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (xr.Name == "SAFE"))
                    uzivatele.Add(new Uzivatel(jobName, index, fileName, customer, url, uString, lang, created));


                foreach (Uzivatel u in uzivatele)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(u);
                }

                JobName = jobName;
                Index = index;
                FileName = fileName;
                Customer = customer;
                URL = url;
                ustring = uString;
                Lang = lang;
                Created = created;
            }

        }
    }

 public string VratJobName()
    { return JobName; }
    public int VratIndex()
        { return Index; }
    public string VratFileName()
        { return FileName; }
    public string VratCustomer()
        { return Customer; }
   public string VratUstring() 
        {return UString;}  
}
```

}

here is action result where i cn store data to viewBag. I dont understand why there its working and at getprd not

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Potvrzeni(ParsovaniXml2Web parsovaniXml) //zobrayi ustring zadany klientem
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)//potvrzeni vyhledavaciho klice + sem chci vlozit parsovani z xml do db a nacteni dat z db

        {
            Read read = new Read();
            read.Precti(parsovaniXml.UString);

            ViewBag.Index = read.Index;
            ViewBag.UString = parsovaniXml.UString;
            ViewBag.Zakaznik = read.Customer;
            ViewBag.Cas = read.Created;
            ViewBag.JobName = read.JobName;
            ViewBag.Filename = read.FileName;


        }
        return View();
    }
```

Why i cant get the data from my two strings?
Kind Regards
Klamath

Comment: include the code to the Read class.

Comment: @klamath12 make a string variable and pass that variable in return and try.

Comment: class read :         public string VratFileName()
            { return FileName; }

Comment: public string VratUstring() 
            {return UString;}

Comment: i tryed to change string to var nothing changed

Comment: update the question with that information.

Comment: Have you tried logging UString and FileName out inside the Read class? maybe they are not set correctly there. How are those being set inside the Read class? I think much more code is needed from that class than just the the two access methods.

Comment: updated  thanx alot

Comment: At least take the time to format you code properly. You really expect us to decipher that rat's nest?

Comment: Ok. I will. thx a lot. I cant get anything normal by myself from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable names are incorrect when you set the properties at the end of the `Precti` method.

The `Precti` method takes a `ustring` parameter which is used to find the XML file.

In the switch/case statement you are setting a local variable `uString` to the found value:

```
case "UString":
     uString = xr.Value;
break;
```

At the end of the method the input variable is getting set to the found value:

`ustring = uString;`

To set the property to the value that you read from the XML file, the line should be:

`UString = uString;`

Just a bit of advice:

You have three variations of casing for `ustring`. You should consider using a more descriptive name for at least one of the variables instead of relying on single character case differences. More descriptive names not only make your code more readable, but also greatly reduce these kinds of errors.

Comment: edited inserted a result controller where i can store data to ViewBag and itw working. I did try store data same waz but its the same result as return... ill take your advice seriously for the next time. Thx

Comment: In the new code you added you are not reading the parsed `UString` value. Instead, you are using the same value that is passed into that method. This line `ViewBag.UString = parsovaniXml.UString;` should be `ViewBag.UString = read.UString;` -- you should see the same behavior once you make this change

Comment: Alternatively, If you want to always use the `UString` value passed into the method and not the one parsed from the XML, then you need to change the `Precti` method to set `UString = ustring`

Comment: Thanks alot. Ill try it 2mmrw. Kind regards.